# Series 1 - 1/2^2 + 1/3 - 1/4^2 + 1/5 - 1/6^2 + 1/7...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is the exercise 2.7.2 e) of the book "Understanding Analysis 2nd edition" from Stephen Abbott, and asks to decide wether this series converges or diverges:
$$ 1-\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4^2}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{6^2}+\dfrac{1}{7}-\dfrac{1}{8^2}\dots $$

I have noticed that
$$\dfrac{1}{3}< 1-\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{3};\\
\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}<1-\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4^2}+\dfrac{1}{5};\\
\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}<1-\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4^2}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{6^2}+\dfrac{1}{7}\\
$$
which is true in general because
$$1-\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{16}-\dfrac{1}{36}-\dfrac{1}{64}-\dots=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(2n)^2}=1-\dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^2}=1-\dfrac{\pi^2}{24}>0.
$$
Thus
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2n+1}<1-\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4^2}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{6^2}+\dfrac{1}{7}-\dfrac{1}{8^2}\dots
$$
Finally, as the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2n+1}$ diverges, so does the series requested.

My two questions are:

I) Is this reasoning correct?

II) Can this exercise be done without using that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$? I would like to find a solution with more elementary tools.

Thank you.

Comment: divergent plus convergent ...just employ definition

Comment: You are correct. It is not necessary to know what $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2$ is, which is deep.. It is enough to know  it exists  in $\Bbb R,$ which can be shown in many ways. For example for $N\geq 2$ we  have $ 0<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^2<$ $1+\sum_{n=2}^N (1/(n-1)-1/n)=$ $1+(1-1/N).$ Or by the Cauchy Condensation Tesr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is good. But after you've proven that $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{2n+1}$ is smaller that the sum of the first $2N+1$ terms of your series, you're done. And all you need for that is that$$\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{4^2}+\cdots+\frac1{(2N)^2}<1.$$This is equivalent to$$\frac1{1^2}+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots+\frac1{N^2}<4,$$which in turn follows from\begin{align}\frac1{1^2}+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots+\frac1{N^2}&<1+\frac1{1\times2}+\frac1{2\times3}+\cdots+\frac1{(N-1)N}\\&=1+1-\frac12+\frac12-\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{N-1}+\frac1N\\&=2+\frac1N\\&<4.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be swayed by the particular case. You have the following

**Lemma** Let $\sum a_n$ be a series (resp. $\sum b_n$ be a convergent series), then the intertwining $x_{2n}=a_n$ and $x_{2n+1}=b_n$ is convergent iff $\sum a_n$ is so.

**Proof** Let us, for short, suppose the indexing starting from zero. Then, we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{2N+1}x_n=\sum_{n=0}^N a_n + \sum_{n=0}^N b_n
$$
this proves the equivalence
$$
\sum x_n\mbox{ converges }\Longleftrightarrow \sum a_n\mbox{ converges }
$$
**end of proof**

Here
$$ 
1+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}\ldots 
$$ 
diverges while
$$\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{4^2}+\dfrac{1}{6^2}+\dfrac{1}{8^2}\ldots 
$$
converges. Hence your series diverges.

Comment: Can the order of summation be changed? $(1+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}\ldots) - (\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\dfrac{1}{4^2}+\dfrac{1}{6^2}+\dfrac{1}{8^2}\ldots)$

Comment: It is not how I reason. I'll add the lemma.

Comment: I tried searching for that, but I got "intertwining operators".  What if I take $a_n = \frac{1}{2n}$  and $b_n = \frac{1}{2n+1}$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter In my lemma $b_n$ is supposed convergent.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  Sorry I can't find this lemma online.  Can you either point me a link or prove it?

Comment: @GNUSupporter Yes, I'll put the proof (it was an exercise in my former training).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77410/discussion-between-duchamp-gerard-h-e-and-gnu-supporter).

Answer (score 1):

$${1\over2n-1}-{1\over(2n)^2}={4n^2-2n+1\over4n^2(2n-1)}\gt{4n^2-4n+1\over4n^2(2n-1)}={2n-1\over4n^2}\ge{1\over4n}$$

so

$$\left(1-{1\over4}\right)+\left({1\over3}-{1\over16}\right)+\left({1\over5}-{1\over36}\right)+\cdots\gt{1\over4}+{1\over8}+{1\over12}+\cdots={1\over4}\left(1+{1\over2}+{1\over3}+\cdots\right)$$